# Disable ClassUnloading with ParallelOld GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection

My app use ParallelOld GC, and while profiling app with JMC I see quite much time spent in class unloading. E.g.

```
Event Type              Name                    Duration (ns)   
GC Phase Pause          GC Pause                191,864,741 

GC Phase Pause Level 1  pre compact             18,946      
GC Phase Pause Level 1  marking phase           140,394,856 
GC Phase Pause Level 2  par mark                40,388,459  
GC Phase Pause Level 2  reference processing    1,073,803   
GC Phase Pause Level 3  SoftReference           756,766     
GC Phase Pause Level 3  WeakReference           61,320      
GC Phase Pause Level 3  FinalReference          238,764     
GC Phase Pause Level 3  PhantomReference        6,014       
GC Phase Pause Level 3  JNI Weak Reference      6,629       
GC Phase Pause Level 2  class unloading         98,902,975  <=========
GC Phase Pause Level 1  summary phase           6,858       
GC Phase Pause Level 1  adjust roots            15,803,657  
GC Phase Pause Level 1  compaction phase        34,518,114  
GC Phase Pause Level 2  drain task setup        1,672       
GC Phase Pause Level 2  dense prefix task setup 1,816       
GC Phase Pause Level 2  steal task setup        234         
GC Phase Pause Level 2  par compact             34,206,466  
GC Phase Pause Level 2  deferred updates        1,624       
GC Phase Pause Level 1  post compact            890,295
```

Here, class unloading phase takes 99 ms out of total 192 ms -- i.e. approx. half of the time. My app does not use dynamic code gen or proxy generation, so I've tried to disable class unloading with -XX:-ClassUnloading, but without success: "class unloading" phase still present in profile, and still takes 1/2-1/3 of Major GC time. I could not find any special flag for disable class unloading for ParallelOld GC (I've tried to find it because there is specific flag for CMS). How could I disable class unloading for ParallelOld GC?

(HotSpot for linux-amd64 1.8.0_102-b14 64-Bit Server VM)

Answer (score 0):

your can try:

`-Xnoclassgc`
Disables garbage collection (GC) of classes. This can save some GC time, which shortens interruptions during the application run. When you specify -Xnoclassgc at startup, the class objects in the application will be left untouched during GC and will always be considered live.

**This can result in more memory being permanently occupied which, if not used carefully, will throw an out of memory exception.**

or to take care of memory size, increase **MetaspaceSize** `-XX:MetaspaceSize=64m` .

A garbage collection is induced to collect the dead classloaders and classes when the class metadata usage reaches MetaspaceSize (12Mbytes on the 32bit client VM and 16Mbytes on the 32bit server VM with larger sizes on the 64bit VMs).

sources http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html

Comment: I've tried -Xnoclassgc, but with no luck: "class unloading" phase still present in profile, and still occupies quite a big part of total GC time...

Comment: i'm surprised, Xnoclassgc cannot be used with CMSClassUnloadingEnabled (disable CMS class unloading options when -Xnoclassgc or -XX:-ClassUnloading are specified.
) , can you try to increase MetaspaceSize -XX:MetaspaceSize=64m  or 128m because anyway it is dangerous to disable classes GC, maybe reduce their GC frequency

Comment: My best guess now is: FlightRecorder explicitly triggered GCs while collecting heap statistics. And _may be_ these explicitly triggered GCs are somehow ignore flags -Xnoclassgc and alike...

Comment: you can check GC activity only by enabling -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCTaskTimeStamps
  to verify without tools